# Looking for an alternative for aloe vera oil for hand disinfectant

Tags: covid-19, alcohol, hygiene

Due to shortages of supplies I need to make homemade alcohol based disinfectants. Basic recipe (and first one) was to add aloe vera (which I don't have) or some kind of essential oil (which also I do not have) to pure alcohol.

I need to know if adding olive oil or nivea cream or something similar are good alternatives to aloe vera.

Answer (score 2):

The Aloe Vera is just to help moisturize the skin and is being used when glycerine can't be bought.

Essential oils are a waste of time, and you need to add a water based substance to moisturize the skin.

You need ethanol or isopropylalcohol as the basis of your sanitizer so that the final concentration is over 60%.

https://youtu.be/WVvtF5uOX3Q

Comment: I have ethanol, i do not have access to glycerine or similar stuff... I do not know will it work if I add soap or liquid soap or other oil for second ingredient...if i dont find anything il just use these with paper handkerchiefs

Comment: @user17865, I wouldn't mix soap and alcohol.  Individually, soap and alcohol are both quite effective at killing viruses, but if you mix them, you might get a chemical reaction that neutralizes one or both.

Comment: @user17865 No oils should be added. Oils can protect viruses from the alcohol.